# Client has no right to have services similar to the Services performed by Client’s staff - is it legal?

Tags: contract-law, terms-of-service, civil-law, competition

Can this provision "The Client has no right to have services similar to the Services performed by Client’s own employees or subcontractors or by other third parties." be illegal?

For example, a contractor has to create a computer program and it means that a client has no right to order similar programs, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing illegal with this. There is just the tiny little problem that the client is unlikely to agree to this contract. I wouldn't if I was the client. And once you suggest a contract that the client doesn't agree to, things get dubious and you might lose the business altogether.